# ProgressBar in Kivy does not update value on UI

Tags: python, popup, kivy

I'm new in Kivy and Python and I want to update a ProgressBar.

The values for the ProgressBar are generated in a while loop and It only updates the value of the ProgressBar when the Task is finished->It takes the last value. I've tested it with schedule a Clock and It won't work.

It took me a long time for this little program and it should become a user interface for a cocktail machine with Raspberry Pi and Touchscreen.

Python

```
def updateProgress(self, waitTime):
    value = 0
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time < waitTime:
        self.popup.ids.pb.value = ((time.time() - start_time) / waitTime)
        time.sleep(0.5)

def makeDrink(self, drink, ingredients):

    self.running = True
    maxTime = 0
    pumpThreads = []
    for ing in ingredients.keys():
        for pump in self.pump_configuration.keys():
            if ing == self.pump_configuration[pump]["value"]:
                waitTime = ingredients[ing] * FLOW_RATE
                if (waitTime > maxTime):
                    maxTime = waitTime
                    pump_t = threading.Thread(target=self.pour, args=(self.pump_configuration[pump]["pin"], waitTime))
                    pumpThreads.append(pump_t)

    for thread in pumpThreads:
        thread.start()

    self.updateProgress(maxTime)

    for thread in pumpThreads:
        thread.join()

    self.popup.ids.start.text = "Start"
    self.popup.ids.start.background_color = (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

Kivy
:
title: root.message
title_color: 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0
bold: True
size_hint: None, None
size: 600, 400

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: "Zutaten:"
        color: 1,1,0,1
        font_size: 20
        bold: True
    Label:
        id: ingredients
        color: 1,1,0,1
        italic: True
    Label:
        text: "Zubereitung:"
        font_size: 20
        color: 1,0,1,1
        bold: True
    Label:
        id: zubereitung
        italic: True
        color: 1,0,1,1
    ProgressBar:
        id: pb
        max: 1
    Button:
        id: start
        background_color: (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        font_size: 30
        text: 'Start'
        on_release: app.root.mixing_menu(root.message)
        on_press: app.root.buttonText('wait')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXaPG.png)

Comment: You are running your `updateProgress()` method on the main thread (where the GUI event loop runs), so the GUI cannot update as long as  that method is running. You should run that method in another thread and use `Clock.schedule_once()` to do the actual ProgressBar update.

Comment: Thank you! Thats it! I've solved the Problem!